Cracks in new house slab foundation?
Here are the pics of our foundation home in Ocala currently under construction with cracks in the garage running from one side to the other and in the kitchen from the sink square to the shower stall square and beyond to the far side of the bedroom wall.
We were informed it has passed inspection and there would be no repairs needed. I am extremely concerned and we addressed it with management - sales agent, their manager and even requested meeting with construction manager. Is this acceptable for a $360K new build? I don't believe it is.


Having a difficult time attaching image.

Have you discussed this with the inspector?  They would be the only ones who could require/request repairs.

No. We just did a pre drywall walk through on June 5. I went into the county record and do not see the name of the inspector on the permit. The parcel is under the builders name.

You are aware that the floor will crack over time, right? Just to the right of your shoe is a "crack control joint" that's designed to catch the cracks and have them run in certain directions. Once your laminate/tile/carpet is down, the floor will crack more and in other places, you just won't know it...

Thank you for the response.  We also have another crack in the garage for the entire width of the garage.  That will not be covered.  This is a new construction and I am very concerned.
